# WPF. How to get the row that the mouse pointer is currently over in a GridControll?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have found this [link](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t546314/how-to-get-the-row-that-the-mouse-pointer-is-currently-over-in-a-gridview). This link explains how to get row over mouse pointer in GridView but I have not found anything about how to do this for GridControl.

Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a similar method for the WPF GridControl. A GridControl is just a container for Views so using the views.CalcHitInfo method will tell you the row index and additional information about the area under the cursor.

See: [Hit Information](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/7557/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/miscellaneous/hit-information)